# Is creating html content using javascript is a good or bad

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen in one of web application, they are creating entire dashboard HTML content using JavaScript methods, Why they are doing this ? by using JavaScript it will take much time to generate HTML tag and hard to debug and edit.
can someone explain what is advantage and disadvantage of using it ?
eg.

```
var ntfytab = new com.xyz.HTM('table',ntfy).init({width:'100%',id:"myTable02"});
var ntfyhad = new com.xyz.HTM('thead',ntfytab).init({});
new com.xyz.HTM('tr',ntfyhad).init({inner : new com.xyz.HTM('th',null)
.init({inner : 'Message'})});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is needed then it is ok, because almost all of the javascript libraries (jquery, prototype etc) plugins generate html in their code to be inserted in the page. 
It is not a problem, it is just difficult and complex to understand :P

Disadvantage is the search engines dont read javascript.

There are lots of advantages. For example if you need to generate and display some html based on some conditions, some events etc then you can do it in javascript.

Think about image sliders, javascript based text editors and other animations effects based on javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Creating tags by Javascript are not rendered by search engines... Or, they may have some sort of privacy control/check so that, no one(lay man) can copy their code..

Answer (score 0):

It can be a suitable solution to output dynamic interfaces, eg tables where the number of rows etc may vary considerably (to output data received via ajax for example).

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend only to create HTML by JS for dynamic content.
for static content alsways use your HTML files which are rendered before JS code will be executed!